# TypeError: Grid is not a constructor. Mongodb node driver

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, node-mongodb-native

I am learning to use mongdb gridfs with nodejs driver. I got stuck on the very first step.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var Grid = require("mongodb").Grid;

MongoClient.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/kkdb", function(err, db) {
   if(err) return console.log("error in connection:>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> ", err); 

   var grid = new Grid(db, 'fs');
   var buffer = new Buffer("Hello world");

   grid.put(buffer, {metadata:{category:'text'}, content_type: 'text'}, function(err, fileInfo) {
       if(!err) {
           console.log("Finished writing file to Mongo");
       }
   });
});
```

When I run this code it shows error:`TypeError: Grid is not a constructor`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 2.X of the Node.js MongoDB driver, this is bound to happen.

As documented [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/upgrade-migration/upgrading/)

> The grid object has been removed, due to its limited GridStore capabilities.

You now have to use a 'GridFSBucket' instead of a 'Grid'

The documentation for this new way doing things can be found [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/tutorials/gridfs/streaming/)

You could also try the 'Legacy GridStore', but since it's deprecated and you have to rewrite anyway, I'd suggest learning the GridFSBucket way.